# NullPointerException ETPush.getInstance Android SDK 4.9.2

Tags: mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush, mobilepush-android

We updated the com.exacttarget.etpushsdk:etsdk to version 4.9.2. After we released the new version of our App we see several NullPointerExceptions that are caused by the SDK.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPush.getInstance(SourceFile:660)
       at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.h.a(SourceFile:62)
       at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETGcmListenerService.onMessageReceived(SourceFile:15)
       at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzn(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzm(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.onMessageReceived(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

The SDK is initialized like the following in the application class:

```
ETNotifications.setNotificationBuilder(new ETNotificationBuilder() {
    @Override
    public NotificationCompat.Builder setupNotificationBuilder(Context context, Bundle bundle) {
        return NotificationUtil.createBuilder(context, bundle.getString("alert"));
    }
});
ETPushConfig pushConfig = new ETPushConfig.Builder(this)
        .setEtAppId(BuildConfig.SALESFORCE_APP_ID)
        .setAccessToken(BuildConfig.SALESFORCE_ACCESS_TOKEN)
        .setGcmSenderId(BuildConfig.GCM_SENDER_ID)
        .setAnalyticsEnabled(true)
        .setLogLevel(Log.DEBUG)
        .build();
try {
    ETPush.configureSdk(pushConfig, new ETPushConfigureSdkListener() {
        @Override
        public void onETPushConfigurationSuccess(ETPush etPush, ETRequestStatus etRequestStatus) {
            // we are not interested in the result
        }

        @Override
        public void onETPushConfigurationFailed(ETException e) {
            Logger.e(TAG, "ETPush configuration failed", e);
        }
    });
} catch (ETException e) {
    Logger.e(TAG, "Could not initialize ETPush", e);
}
```

It seems like the SDK is not handling the case when the GcmListenerService returns before the ETPush.configureSdk() finished (asynchronously) initializing ETPush.

Comment: It would appear you are correct.  I will open a bug for prioritization.

Comment: Ralph, we have a fix being reviewed.  A release is forthcoming though I cannot provide an exact date.  I will post an answer to this question when the release is public.

Answer (score 0):

Version 4.9.3 was just released to correct this problem: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/  Thank you for bringing it to our attention.